# Prevent the default behavior of exiting cellEdit on Enter

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to avoid the default behavior of Enter key as it exits the cell edit in ag-grid. I have seen some ways to add eventListeners and avoid enter, but unable to achieve that in reactjs. Has someone tried any other approach to stop the default behavior on Enter?